# Suspend redrawing while changing multiple children

Tags: ios, xamarin

I have a `UIViewController` that after asynchronously loading some data needs to resize some child views (Some UITableViews, and some UIScrollViews). This works just fine in the simulator, but on an actual device, it hangs for a long time (as much as 30 seconds in one case). I think the problem is that it wants to recalculate everything after each changed to the child view and I would like to be able to tell it to defer any recalculations until I've resized everything, but I'm drawing a blank on finding a way to do that. Is there a mechanism to do this?

So what I'm doing is something like this (I'm using C# with Xamarin but input in Obj-C would also be appreciated!):

```
// Need to suspend layout here... 
MyTable.Frame = new RectangleF(...);
SomeOtherTable.Frame = new RectangleF(...);
ScrollView.ContentSize = new SizeF(...);
AnotherScrollView.ContentSize = new SizeF(...);
AnotherScrollView.Frame = new RectangleF(...);
// Ok - now you can redraw!
```

**Update**: Jacob's suggestion of disabling animation didn't seem to help, but I think I've isolated the problem to the table resizing. They seem to have the biggest impact on performance, but I'm not sure why, or how to mitigate the problem. I may follow up with a separate question on that.

Comment: Have you tried disabling animation? For a one-liner, see: https://gist.github.com/jfoshee/5008117

Comment: @JacobFoshee: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I see; you may want to update your question w/ that info. Wish I had more ideas.